# VueJS 3 and vue-google-charts

Tags: vuejs3

I am a beginner in VueJS. I am trying to create some visualization using vue-google-charts library but I am unable to do. I followed some online tutorials like [this](https://www.positronx.io/how-to-integrate-and-use-google-pie-chart-in-vue-js/).

But I am receiving this error in console:

```
[Vue warn]: Property "$createElement" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <GChart type="PieChart" options= 
Object { width: 1100, height: 400 }
 data= 
Array(6) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […] ]
 > 
  at <App> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6870
[Vue warn]: Property "_self" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. 
  at <GChart type="PieChart" options= 
Object { width: 1100, height: 400 }
 data= 
Array(6) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […] ]
 > 
  at <App> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6870
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <GChart type="PieChart" options= 
Object { width: 1100, height: 400 }
 data= 
Array(6) [ (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […], (2) […] ]
 > 
  at <App> 
  at <App>
```

Answer (score 3):

got the same problem on VueJS 3, I tried serveral packages end up using a different library.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs
```